# IsChcked() doesn't response to the Checkbox state (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, ischecked

Hi I have  2 `CheckBox` (`cb1`, `cb2`). I set default values to

```
cb1.setchecked(true)
cb2.setchecked(false).
```

Then I set an `OnClickListener` to `cb2`. In the the `onClick` method I wrote :

```
cb2.SetChecked(true);  
cb1.SetChecked(false);
```

The problem is that by visibility it's working, the `cb2` is checked and the cb1 unchecked, **but** when I check the `Checkbox` state with

```
boolean state = cb2.IsChecked();
```

It returns false and `cb1.IsChecked();`  returns true altough it's the opposite(by visibility) .

Then I concluded that it only takes the default values that I set to  the `Checkbox`?
And the `OnClickListener` only takes effect on screen but not in code?

Comment: add your code please

Answer (score 0):

How about using `onCheckedChangeListener()` with your checkbox?

```
cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        cb2.setChecked(isChecked);
        cb1.setChecked(!isChecked);
    }
};
```

Comment: This should be a comment instead of answer

Comment: Well, I know about that but I can't yet because of my rep. ... I will modify my answer with more detail.